# connect via WebSocket HTML5 client app with Java server app in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, html

I am currently working on some project in NetBeans IDE using HTML5 and JavaScript.

My new task is to use WebSocket in JavaScript and connect to server. Since I have some previous knowledge of Java I decided to make that in Java. But am new with this server thing, so I am interested is it possible to connect this two application in Windows and how to do it? Can I just provide in JavaScript hostname "localhost" and port number, and than i Java app provide port number?
Or do I need install TomCat or some other server program, and if so, how do I make in NetBeans that my HTML5 app is running on that server instead of localhost?

Thank you